# Memory crash in C++ with strings

Tags: c++, string, memory

I'm am doing a program (machine learning course) in which I have to read 120.000 files, and save each line of each file in a string[]. If a line repeats I just do not add it in my dictionary.
I have declared a string dic[100000] and with it I'am able to handle more or less 20.000 files, not more.
The problem is that if I declare string dic[200000] program compiles but crashes in .exe, same if I declare dic[100000], dic2[100000].
Can anyone suggest me any method to use memory in a proper manner so that I can handle 120.000 files?

Comment: Try allocating that on heap

Comment: You should post your code to help us see what is happening.

Comment: Use std::vector<std::string>.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are probably exceeding the stack size of your program. That's something that can be configured when compiling as far as I can remember; in any case, you should be using the *heap* instead of the *stack*; this is: use dynamic memory. Example:

```
string *dic = new string[200000];
...
delete [] dic;
```

As you can see, you have to take care of releasing the memory in this case, but you can use much more memory.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try.

Comment: This is considered bad practice. If your really-really want to stick to `string[]` then do `std::unique_ptr<string[]> dic(new string[20000])` but you are much better off using `vector<string>` as others already suggested.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::deque<std::string>` to avoid huge contiguous allocations.

Comment: It seems to work!!!
How can I transform to dynamic this matrix?  float MB [111000] [2];

Comment: Botond Denes, sorry I'm not a pro c++ user. Just a beginner.
In order to use std::deque<...> I have just to add it at the top of my program or something else?
And to use vector<string> do I have to change the syntax all over the program?

Comment: You just need to include the appropriate header (`#include <vector>` or `#include <deque>`) and of course the declaration of your `dic` variable. Other than that you can use it the same way.

Comment: If I try to do std::unique_ptr<string[]> dic(new string[650000]); it gaves me these errors: unique:ptr is not a member of 'std', expected primary-ex befor [, dic was not declared in this scope

Comment: `#include <memory>`

Comment: Actually the point of my answer was to explain why he was getting that error. The example is a pretty simple one.

Apart from that, I don't think that's a bad practice *by default*. If he were implementing a class, depending on the needs it could make sense to allocate the array on instantiation time and deallocating it in the destructor. Which doesn't mean `std::unique_ptr` isn't a good option, of course.

In my opinion using `vector<string>` should be restricted depending on the needs. If the size of the array is fixed, using such class only introduces some unnecessary overhead.